# How to call Binance /futures/data/openInterestHist Market Data Endpoint?

Tags: python, python-requests, binance

The documentation states that the request header must contain the api key.

My request looks like this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': api_key
}

requests.get('https://binance.com/futures/data/openInterestHist?symbol=BTCUSD&period="5m"&limit=30', headers=headers)
```

Result is:
`<Response [400]>`

I also tried to send a signed request with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Neptun, you can try to see the response body by doing `response = requests.get(...)` then `print(response.data)` It may give you hint about what you are doing wrong :)

Comment: thanks @Thom the response is `access denied` I don't get why as i'm sending the API key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.binance.com/futures/data/openInterestHist?symbol=BTCUSDT&period=5m&limit=30

All the same but without 
quotation mark.
And BTCUSD isn't futures. BTCUSDT is required.